# How to clear coordinate where i want on google maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I made polygon on maps fill black and tried to clear current location use addHole method.
But if holes overlap each other, polygon with holes appear i don't want!
Please give me answer...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn15M.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RajLA.jpg

Plus, Is there exist a way clear the polygon given gps coordinate??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TileOverlay.remove()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay#remove) method to remove a tile overlay or use [`tileOverlay.clearTileCache();`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay#clear) to force a refresh. This will cause all the tiles on this overlay to be reloaded. If the tiles provided by the `TileProvider` change, you must call `clearTileCache()` afterwards to ensure that the previous tiles are no longer rendered.